# Insert Rows - looping macro function - based on number in cell

Tags: excel, vba

Newbie with macros/vba here.

I have a template with two buttons - one copies and pastes the sheet into a new tab, the second will add rows based on a Command button from manual input

Is there anyway for me to edit the code so that it will input the number of rows to add based on a cell value within the template - for example, add the number of rows based on the value in Cell D16

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim numrow
numrow = Application.InputBox("Please enter number of rows to add. Note: please refer to total installments (Cell D16)", "Insert Row", , , , , , 1)

If IsNumeric(numrow) Then

For i = 1 To numrow

Call INRW

Next i
End If

End Sub
```

The code for INRW as below

```
Sub INRW()

ActiveSheet.Unprotect "Password"

Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select

ActiveCell.Offset(-2).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

Range("B22").End(xlDown).Offset(-1).Copy
Range("B22").End(xlDown).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
Range("B22").End(xlDown).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

Range("H22").End(xlDown).Offset(-1).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight)).Copy
Range("H22").End(xlDown).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
ActiveCell.Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

ActiveSheet.Protect "Password"

End Sub
```

Or would it be possible for me to directly run INRW after copying the sheet?

```
Public Sub CopySheetAndRename()
    Dim newName As String

    On Error Resume Next
    newName = InputBox("Enter the name for the copied worksheet")

    If newName <> "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Name = newName
        Range("$D$3").Value = newName
    End If

    Dim n As Name
    For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    n.Visible = True
    Next n

End Sub
```

The file was originally working, I was trying to streamline the process of using the file.

The purpose of the file is for

1. User to make a copy of the template tab using the button - CopySheetAndRename
2. The user to input the name of the tab - which would be a unique ID - that matched information linking to a database of information in the same workbook but on a different tab
3. Cells within the newly generated template would then vlookup back to the database to extract bits of data relevant to that unique id - one of which would be a numeric amount for amount of columns to add
4. In the current file, the user would then have to manually input the amount of rows to add based on this information
5. However I was attempting to streamline the process by having the macro add the specified amount of rows after the new sheet was generated.
6. I would like to keep the input box as the user may choose to add rows beyond than the amount specified in D16

Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Range("D16").Value
```

or

```
Cells(16, 4).Value
```

to reference the value in Cell D16

If you want to get rid of the input box, simply replace it with the InputBox statement by

```
numrow = Range("D16").Value
```

If you are going to set it as the default value of the input box, put it in the 3rd argument of the InputBox() method call

```
numrow = Application.InputBox("Please enter number of rows to add. Note: please refer to total installments (Cell D16)", "Insert Row", Range("D16").Value, , , , , 1)
```

For your latest edited version, I do not see why copying the sheet is related to the original question.

Comment: Sorry add -  Range("D16").Value to which part of the code?

Comment: Do you want to replace the input box value by Cell D16 value? If so, `numrow = Range("D16").Value`

Comment: I tried changing 'numrow = Application.InputBox("Please enter number of rows to add. Note: please refer to total installments (Cell D16)", "Insert Row", , , , , , 1)' to 'numrow = Range("D16").Value' doesn't seem to be working unfortunately

Is it because it's a commandbutton?

Comment: Or could it be possible for me to

1) Copy a new worksheet
2) Then call INRW based on the value in D16

Will paste the copy new worksheet code in the next comment

Comment: Do u want to keep the input box?

Comment: Can you explain how it doesn't seem to be working? what error did you encounter?

Comment: Refer to my answer, put Range("D16") in the 3rd argument of InputBox() method call to make it as the default value

Comment: I updated the question hope it puts my question into better perspective